# Change UIImage in Objective-C Program

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to change a UIImage in a xib file but it wouldn't change until I comment on this code. I changed image name in this code to but it's not helped me.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgHeaderImage;

    if([Util getStringData:kAppNameWhiteImage] !=nil){

    [self.imgHeaderImage sd_setImageWithURL:[Util EncodedURL:[Util getStringData:kAppNameImage]] completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
        if (image == nil)
        {
            self.imgHeaderImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo Original"];
        }
        else
        {
            self.imgHeaderImage.image = image;
        }
    }];
} else {
    self.imgHeaderImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo Original"];
}
```

I'm not familiar with Objective-C that why cannot solve this problem. please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: comment first if condition `if([Util getStringData:kAppNameWhiteImage] !=nil)` and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to track down the constant: `kAppNameWhiteImage` and change it’s value. Do a search in the project.  In the code you shared `“Logo Original”` is only loaded if it cant get a valid image from `kAppNameWhiteImage`.

Comment: #define kAppNameWhiteImage @"AppNameWhiteImage"  


its define in my Header File, now what should I do to change the image. and I don't mess with app functionality too.

Comment: Next, go to [Util getStringData:kAppNameWhiteImage] and figure out what that function is doing.  If AppNameWhiteImage is the name of a file change the name to the file you want to use.  Search the code to see if there is anywhere else in your project that it is being referenced.  Just start experimenting.  Also, look in the Assets.xcassets folder and see if there is any asset named AppNameWhiteImage.  Replace it with what you want.

Comment: And dont be shy about experimenting.  You can't break anything if you can just go back to the original in git.

Answer (score 0):

Since the context of the whole issue is not particularly sufficient, I can only speculate roughly.

Please forgive me if my answer is not accurate.

Since the code is executed only after the Xib file has been loaded, the code you presented is executed.

So no matter how you modify the Image in Xib, but the Code remains the same, the result will always be obtained after the Code is executed. The Logo of the Original. Because Code is executed after the Xib file is loaded.